# How to check for a property in a vertex or its child using gremlin-cosmos

Tags: gremlin, gremlin-server, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi, gremlinpython

I am traversing a path `a,b,c,d` in my graph where `a,b,c,d` are the nodes along the traversed path.

```
(a)->(b)->(c)->(d)
```

My traversal will end at `node d` as `node d` is a leaf node.

I want my traversal to cover all nodes from `a` to `d` and it must not come to a halt before it reaches node `d`.

The goal of the traversal is to find out if a certain property exists in node `c` or `d`. If for example the property does not exit in node `c`, I'd like to check if it does exist in its child node `d` first before the path is rendered invalid.

How do I achieve this with gremlin query on cosmos? Is there such a thing as an *optional* `has()` in Gremlin?

Nodes `c` and `d` are labeled differently however they have the same properties.

Currently, I have this query, but it would fail if node `c` didn't have the property of interest even though node `d` might have it.

```
G.V().hasLabel('a').out().as('b').out().as('c').has('status', 'patched').out().as('d').has('status', 'patched')
```

If either node `c` or node `d` have the property `'status': 'patched'` is good enough and the path is valid (aka. I want that path in my result to the query)

I am doing this on CosmosDB, so please only provide answers using supported steps found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/gremlin/support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The goal of the traversal is to find out if a certain property exists in node c **or** d.

This sounds like an or() step:

```
G.V().hasLabel('a').out().out().or(
    __.has('status', 'patched').out(),
    __.out().has('status', 'patched')
  ).path()
```